# MySQL query for multiple users and multiple tables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to make a query to achieve the following situation. I want a user to be able to view their events and activities (two different tables), along with any events/activities of organizations they belong to sorted by date

Events Table

```
eventID |  eventTitle   | eventBy   | eventDate
1           Event 1        1          2012/10/11
2           Event 2        2          2012/10/08
3           Event 3        3          2012/10/05
```

Activities table

```
postID     |   postTitle  |  postBy  |    postDate
  1            activity 1       1          2012/10/07
  2            activity 2       2          2012/10/09
```

orgMembers table

```
orgID  |  userID
 2             1            //userID 1 is a member of groupID 2
```

Anyway, I'm trying to get the results to look be the following if userid 1 is viewing the page

```
 Title            By            Date
Activity 1        1          2012/10/07
Event 2           2          2012/10/08
Activity 2        2          2012/10/09
Event 1           1          2012/10/11
```

This query results in ONLY my posts only showing, not the organization that I'm a member of too.

```
select eventTitle as title, eventID as ids, eventBy as byUser, users.username, eventDate as date from events
inner join users on users.userid = events.eventBy
where eventBy in (select distinct g1.userID from orgMembers g1
                 inner join orgMembers g2 on g1.orgID = g2.orgID
                 where g2.userID = '$id') 
                 or eventBy = '$id' 

UNION 

select postTitle as description, postID as ids, postBy as byUser, users.username, postDate as date from posts
inner join users on users.userid = posts.postBy
where postBy in (SELECT distinct g1.userID FROM orgMembers g1
                 inner join orgMembers g2 on g1.orgID = g2.orgID
                 where g2.userID = '$id') 
                 or postBy = '$id'

Order BY date"
```

Comment: What are eventBy and activityBy ? Either a userID or a groupID ? You don't mix these two things, do you ?

Comment: it's the userid of the person who created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using

```
WHERE eventby IN
```

replace 1 with your user id

you might want to use `UNION` to select from 2 tables events and activities

(select eventInfo as Ttile,eventBy as By, eventDate as Date from Events where Eventby in (SELECT userid FROM groups WHERE groupid = (SELECT groupid FROM groups WHERE userid = 1)))
UNION
(select activityInfo  as Ttile,activityInfo  as By, activityDate  as Date from Activities where activityBy  in (SELECT userid FROM groups WHERE groupid = (SELECT groupid FROM groups WHERE userid = 1))) Order BY Date

do the same with activities and the do union and sort

Comment: So it's essentially a query in a query? How do I handle the user's events/activites, just another union?

Comment: check the main answer again with complete query, you might want to check for field name etc, as I have not run this in real

Comment: Thanks, so in addition to this, to find my own activities/events I'd just do something like UNION select activityInfo.... where userid = $myuserid? (instead of in select userid....)

Comment: use the above query, the query selects from 2 tables and then the union is used between , finally sorted by date, UNION combines the results of 2 sql queries, finally it is just 1 query

Comment: I see how the query works for acquiring a group's events/activities. Maybe I'm misunderstanding it, but I'm not seeing where the user's activities/events are queried. There are events/activities that may not be associated with any groups, and those still have to show up. Wouldn't I simply need an additional UNION select activityInfo as Ttile,activityInfo as By, activityDate as Date from Activities where activityBy where userid = '1'

Comment: the user also belongs to the same group so we donot need to specify the user again, but if the user may not be in a group use or userid=1

Comment: Hmm, for some reason only my events are showing up, not the group's events too.

Answer (score 1):

The `OR eventBy = 1`
and `OR activityBy = 1` must be added if one user can be "without group". If all users have at least one group, you can remove them

```
SELECT eventInfo as title, eventBy as By, eventDate as Date
FROM event
WHERE eventBy IN (select distinct g1.userId from groups g1
                   inner join groups g2 on g1.groupId = g2.groupId
                   where g2.userId = 1)
OR eventBy = 1 

UNION
SELECT activityInfo as title, activityBy as By, activityDate as Date
FROM Activity
WHERE activityBy = (select distinct g1.userId from groups g1
                   inner join groups g2 on g1.groupId = g2.groupId
                   where g2.userId = 1)
OR activityBy = 1
```